# Android app won't update from other app stores after key upgrade

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-signing, app-update

I am in a big trouble with update my app from multiple app stores.
So the problem is that after i performed key upgrade from play console for my app, my users can't update their apps with other app stores. They can update just with Google Play and nothing else.
After contacting google play support, they told me to create new upload key (i don't know why) to fix this problem. i have created a new one and they performed in my app.
So i didn't perform new upload key for other app stores because i afraid about their updating progress going wrong.
Every app stores except play store are ok and can update app if it downloaded from whenever except play store. and play store only show update button it user downloaded previous app version from app store only.
What can i do considering the play console key upgrade cannot be undone ?
What is the real problem of this situation that i stuck ?

Comment: Why would you expect someone who downloads the app from one app store to be able to update it on another?  That's not a feature that any of them support.  If it was working, it was sheer luck, not design.  And that kind of behavior could never work with the new Google Play Signing, where they actual key used to sign your app is stored on Google's servers.

Comment: It is usual that someone has multiple app stores.

Comment: Not really, very few people as a percentage use alternate app stores.  But even then, they wouldn't likely update it from one they didn't download, they would update it from the one they did, generally by auto-update.  If it ever worked previously, it wasn't an intended feature.  I wouldn't expect them to fix such a niche use case, especially as it helps something they don't really prefer you do at all (use a 3rd party app store).